# Java Auto increment

Tags: java

Why is the output of the following code 5 and not 4?

```
public class Test
{
    public static void run(int x)
    {
        while(x < 5)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
            x++;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
              run(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's 5 because the while loop doesn't stop until it's 5.

Comment: when its 4 based on your condition it goes inside and perform ++ ..so that result is 5

Comment: but  { i++ in  } Block Statement scope

Comment: Why do you think it should be 4 not 5?

Comment: i++ in Block of code scope  { }

Answer (score -1):

Just walk through what's happening.

Your loop will keep looping "while x is less then 5", so on your last loop `x` will be equal to 4. Then, inside you're loop, you perform `x++`, so add 1 to `x`. `x` is no longer less then 5 (it is 5), so your loop is done and you print out the value.

If you only want to loop until `x` is equal to 4, simply change your loop condition to: `while(x < 4)`, *or* add an if statement to check the value of `x` before you increase it:

```
if(x == 4){
break;  //Exit the loop
}
```

Comment: why?loop will keep looping
i++ in { } block statement scope

Comment: Right now you're looping on _x_, not _i_. _x_ was assigned outside of the loop's scope, so _x++_ will be changing _x_'s value.

Comment: I Know  Thanks  varibale x   Outside loop

Answer (score -1):

Think about what `while (x < 5) { ... }` actually says.

It says:

> Keep on looping as long as `x < 5` is `true`.

Hint: `x < 5` is true when `x` is 4.  The loop won't end until the expression `x < 5` becomes false.  What is the first value of `x` for which `x < 5` evaluates to false?

Comment: Please do. As far as I can see, both my and Stephen's answers answer the question as it is currently worded.